# I dont want to print repeated lines based on column 6 and 7

Tags: sorting, awk, sed

I don't want to print repeated lines based on column 6 and 7. `sort -u` does not seem to help

**cat /tmp/testing :-**

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  52662693 Feb 27 13:11 /home/something/bin/proxy_exec
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  27441394 Feb 27 13:12 /home/something/bin/keychain_exec
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  45570820 Feb 27 13:11 /home/something/bin/wallnut_exec
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  10942993 Feb 27 13:12 /home/something/bin/log_exec
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 137922408 Apr 16 03:43 /home/something/bin/android_exec
```

When I try `cat /tmp/testing | sort -u -k 6,6 -k 7,7` I get :-

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 137922408 Apr 16 03:43 /home/something/bin/android_exec
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  52662693 Feb 27 13:11 /home/something/bin/proxy_exec
```

Desired output is below, as that is the only file different from others based on month and date column

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 137922408 Apr 16 03:43 /home/something/bin/android_exec
```

Comment: uniq -u  works, but how to use it with column 6 and 7 or is there a way to use awk?

Comment: Actually figured it out.

cat /tmp/testing | awk '{print $9,$6,$7}' | uniq -u  -f 1

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good that you found a solution but what you have shown in the desired output and what you have figured out is different?

Comment: See http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed

```
sed -E '/^\s*(\S+\s+){5}Feb\s+27/d' testing
```

tried on gnu awk

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$6$7;next} a!=$6$7{print}' testing
```

Comment: The awk will fail if the output comes from `ls -lt`, ie. the desired single line comes first.

Answer (score 0):

*[not] to print repeated lines based on column 6 and 7* using awk, you could:

```
$ awk '
++seen[$6,$7]==1 {          # count seen instances
    keep[$6,$7]=$0          # keep first seen ones       
}
END {                       # in the end
    for(i in seen)
        if(seen[i]==1)      # the ones seen only once
            print keep[i]   # get printed
}' file                     # from file or pipe your ls to the awk
```

Output for given input:

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 137922408 Apr 16 03:43 /home/something/bin/android_exec
```

**Notice**: All standard warnings against parsing `ls` output still apply.